# How can I convert a date from the format "dd/mm/yyyy" to "yyyy/dd/mm"?

Tags: c#

I have a Textbox in which the user is supposed to enter a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, this date is stored as `yyyy/mm/dd` in the database.

So I want the user to enter the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and later I want to convert to `yyyy/mm/dd` so that I can query database.

How can I convert the user input date `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: What is your date datatype in the database?  I hope it's a date/time field.

Comment: In your database, it should be a `DATETIME` datatype, and as such, it doesn't have any format - it's just the value.

Comment: date datatype in the database is 'DATE'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and maybe dirty:

```
string reformattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

This, of course, assumes that the content of the Textbox will always be in the assumed format, so their should be checks in before to ensure that. There's also the much safer way which does not need additional checks:

```
DateTime result;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
{
    // Here you can safely use result
    string reformattedDate = result.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
} else {
    // Screw the user
}
```

This will try to parse the content of the Textbox and return it to your via the `out result`, if successful, it will return true. Otherwise you can rest assured that the input was either not in the assumed format, or not a valid Date.

Please also be aware that `ParseExact` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` or an `ArgumentException` if the conversion fails.

- [MSDN Article for ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)
- [MSDN Article for TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

> I have a text box in which the user is supposed to enter a date in dd/mm/yyyy format, this date is stored as yyyy/mm/dd in the database.

The obvious answer to this is: use a DateTimePicker and a parameterized query before wrestling with a string conversion. It will save you *a lot* of headache in the long run.

Comment: I am getting the error as No overload for method 'ToDateTime' takes '3' argument

Comment: It's best to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` when handling user input otherwise you'll have to add your own exception handling.

Comment: @Spolto: Of course, I left it out because the question sounded like he already knew how to validate the input. On second thought I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you store a date in the database, then store it as a date not as a string. Then you will only have one format: what the user typed in.

Using DateTime.Parse (or TryParse, or the "Exact" versions) you can convert from the typed-in string to a DateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at

[DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

and

[DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  Somthing like `dateTimeval.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

```
string dateString = "30/01/2010";
DateTime dateTimeVal;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,"dd/MM/yyyy", null,DateTimeStyles.None,out dateTimeVal))
{
    string newFormat = dateTimeVal.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the date in a `DateTime` field in the database, the date is not actually stored in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

To render the date use:

```
string formattedDate = dateFromDb.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

To convert a `date` string for a particular format you can use:

```
DateTime value;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
  date,
  "dd/MM/yyyy", 
  new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
  out value))
{
  Console.Write(value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
}
else
{
  Console.Write("Date parse failed!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> this date is stored as yyyy/mm/dd in
>   the database

I hope that this is not true. I hope that you store the date as a `datetime` value in the database and not as a `varchar` value.

If you store the date as a `datetime` value, there is no point in converting the date string from one format to another, you should parse the string to a `DateTime` value.

Use the `ParseExact` method to parse a string from a specific format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(theDateTextbox.Text, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to convert a DateTime to a string:

```
dateTime.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

[Here are the different format of ToString](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

But I think it is better to use a DateTimePicker, you're sure to have a date and user can use keyboard to input a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "20/12/2010"; // dd/mm/yyyy
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
{
    string result = d.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```